# Is there a test JsonRpc server out there?

Tags: json-rpc

Is there any server on the Internet that uses JsonRpc and is publically available?

I want to test a JsonRpc client.

Does Google have any page that allows reading of anything with JsonRpc? Does YouTube? Does Facebook? Does W3C?

The JsonRpc server that i want to talk to isn't responding; and i'm trying to figure out if it's because they don't support JsonRpc.

Answer (score 3):

Random.org has a nice [api](https://api.random.org/) for generating random numbers.

For example, using Python with [jsonrpcclient](https://www.jsonrpcclient.com/):

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from jsonrpcclient import request, parse
>>> response = requests.post("http://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke", request("generateIntegers", params={"apiKey": "(yourkey)", "n": 3, "min": 0, "max": 10}))
>>> parsed = parse(response.json())
>>> parsed.result
{'bitsLeft': 249920, 'advisoryDelay': 0, 'bitsUsed': 10, 'random': {'data': [9, 4, 2], 'completionTime': '2015-04-09 00:52:22Z'}, 'requestsLeft': 992}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Atlassian Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com) supports it, but I'm not sure they have a test instance.  Plus, their implementation isn't quite 100% correct (https://developer.atlassian.com/x/AwCF)